# Session issue when having async Session_Start method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I recently started using .NET 4.5 over .NET 4.0, and I am loving the `async` feature.

However, when using it in ASP .NET in the Session_Start event in my Global.asax, no matter what I do (if I perform an await and access a session), it'll cause an error.

Here's the code. I'm sure you can replicate the issue. The thing is - how do I solve it?

```
protected async void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stuff = await UserAccess.RetrieveSomeStuff();
    Session["Stuff"] = stuff;
}
```

The error I am receiving is as follows.

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

I also tried the following code with no luck.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stuffTask = UserAccess.RetrieveSomeStuff();
    stuffTask.Wait();

    Session["Stuff"] = stuffTask.Result;
}
```

In that scenario, it'll have a status of `WaitingForActivation` constantly, which could indicate that it's not being put into the queue of tasks to be executed by the system (maybe because the system is waiting for the `Wait()` call itself to finish?).

I also tried starting the task manually. In that case, it just crashes, as you can't manually start a task. It has to be done by the system as far as I am concerned.

Any clue? This one is tough.

Comment: Have you tried manually starting the Task via Task.Factory.StartNew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `InvalidOperationException` you're getting is ASP.NET's way of telling you that you can't have an `async` handler for that event.

But really, what you want to do is *start* some asynchronous resource initializing, and then (asynchronously) wait for it later when you actually need it. So the object in your `Session` should really be a `Task<T>`, like this:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Stuff"] = LoadMyDataAsync();
}

static async Task<int> LoadMyDataAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 13;
}
```

And then you can use it like this (this example is an ASP.NET MVC 4 controller, but WebAPI and async WebPages can use a similar technique):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = await (Session["Stuff"] as Task<int>);
    return View();
}
```

It's a bit awkward because `Session` isn't strongly typed.

Comment: I ended up using this by making an extension method to Session which, (through generics) was strong-typed.

Comment: And this would be with the use of AsynCTP package?

Comment: @ArmanBimatov: No. You cannot safely use AsyncCTP or Microsoft.Bcl.Async on ASP.NET.

Comment: So what is the library used here for await/async? What is the namespace?

Comment: it does not work... if you define  async Task<ActionResult>, then, on the call on Session_Start  Session["Stuff"] = LoadMyDataAsync();, you have to use await LoadMyDataAsync();,

Comment: @Diego: Yes, you have to `await` the task stored in the session bag, just like the code in my answer does.