# async getting no where

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am refactoring my ASP MVC code in session_start in Global.asax.cs with an async call to external service.  I either get a white page with endless spinning in IE, or execution immediately returns to the calling thread.  In the Session_start() when I tried .Result, I got white page with spinning IE icon. When I tried .ContinueWith(), the execution return to the next line which depends on the result from the async.  Thus authResult is always null. Can someone help?  Thanks.

**This is from the Session_Start()**

```
         if (Session["userProfile"] == null) {
           //call into an async method
           //authResult = uc.checkUserViaWebApi(networkLogin[userLoginIdx]).Result;
           var userProfileTask = uc.checkUserViaWebApi(networkLogin[userLoginIdx])
             .ContinueWith(result => {
               if (result.IsCompleted) {
                 authResult = result.Result;
               }
             });

           Task.WhenAll(userProfileTask);

           if (authResult.Result == enumAuthenticationResult.Authorized) {
```

**This is from User_Controller class**

```
   public async Task < AuthResult > checkUserViaWebApi(string networkName) {
       UserProfile _thisProfile = await VhaHelpersLib.WebApiBroker.Get < UserProfile > (
         System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userWebApiEndpoint"], "User/Profile/" + networkName);


       AuthResult authenticationResult = new AuthResult();

       if (_thisProfile == null) /*no user profile*/ {
         authenticationResult.Result = enumAuthenticationResult.NoLSV;
         authenticationResult.Controller = "AccessRequest";
         authenticationResult.Action = "LSVInstruction";
       }
```

**This is helper class that does the actual call using HttpClient**

```
 public static async Task<T> Get<T>(string baseUrl, string urlSegment)
    {
      string content = string.Empty;
      using(HttpClient client = GetClient(baseUrl))
      {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlSegment.TrimStart('/')).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
          content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
      }
```

Comment: you may want to look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167243/session-issue-when-having-async-session-start-method

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked.

Comment: It looks like the only reason you are using async is because you are using `HttpClient`, use can use [`WebClient.DownloadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and not be async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to call User_Controller from **Session_Start**.

You want to call VhaHelpersLib directly inside **Session_Start**, if VhaHelpersLib doesn't have any dependencies.

Since Session_Start is not async, you want to use **Result**.

```
var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userWebApiEndpoint"];
 UserProfile profile = await VhaHelpersLib.WebApiBroker.Get<UserProfile>(
        setting, "User/Profile/" + networkName).Result;

if (profile == enumAuthenticationResult.Authorized) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The user_controller has the business logic to determine the authorization levels.  The code snippet only shows small part of the logic.  It is not the session_start() concern.  In addition, the await you suggested won't compile because that would require signature for session_start() to be changed async.

Comment: Did you use **Result** at the end? Basically, Result would block until the task is completed. For example, in your original question, `var userProfileTask = uc.checkUserViaWebApi(networkLogin[userLoginIdx]).Result;`

Comment: Thank you.  It worked and I left the hefty business logic in the user_controller class.